# Friendly forwarding after login doesn't work after adding friendly_id to the user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

The core of my app is build from [Michael Hartl's rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/). Recently I changed the User DB so the `name` column is named `username` and I also added in friendly_id for prettier URLs. I updated everywhere I could find in accordance with these changes and everything works smoothly except for friendly forwarding after a user logs in. e.g. if a non logged in user visits a user edit page they are taken to the login page, after they login they should be taken to their edit page. But instead it just logs them in and stays on the login page.

I cant see anywhere that would need changing so it works again and from what I can see it should work

**session controller**

```
 def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**user controller**

```
 before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]

 def edit
 end

private


    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end


    def correct_user
      @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
```

**application controller**

```
def redirect_back_or(path)
  redirect_to request.referer || path
end



  private

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "You gotta login first!"
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end
```

**session helper**

```
  # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
  end
```

Anyone know where the problem might lie?

**Update**

after chatting with @vishal the redirect is done from the application controller `redirect_back_or` method

```
 def redirect_back_or(path)
  redirect_to request.referer || path
 end
```

If I change it to

```
def redirect_back_or(path)
  redirect_to root_path || path
end
```

I am taken to the root path so I know this line os most likely the culprit.

In-between it working and not working I added the mailboxer gem for private messages, changed the Users db `name` to `username` and added friendly_id to the `username` column. Maybe something there might stand out to you as a cause for it stop working.

Comment: Do you have `before_action :logged_in_user` in your UsersController? The `store_location` is called only in `logged_in_user` which doesn't seem to have been added as a before filter.

Comment: @Vishal forgot to add it in. I've updated the question now

Comment: Can you include your `store_location` method too?

Comment: @Vishal  Added it just after my edit haha. At the bottom in session helper

Comment: Do you have `include SessionsHelper` in your ApplicationController?

Comment: Yes. It was all working fine before I changed `name` to `username` in the Users db and added friendly_id to `username`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106780/discussion-between-vishal-and-user3234020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application controller, change redirect_back_or(path) method to this.

```
    def redirect_back_or(path)
      redirect_to session[:forwarding_url] || path
      session.delete(:forwarding_url)
    end
```

You had `redirect_to request.referer` before which was responsible for redirecting you to the last url, that is, the login_url.

I have no idea why you're defining two different methods - 1 in ApplicationController & 1 in SessionsHelper - with the same name but different intended behaviors though.

Comment: Also, in Michael Hartl's rails tutorial that you mentioned, it's `request.referrer` and not `request.referer`. Don't know if that makes any difference but just putting it out there.

Comment: Yes thats it. Looking at my commit history I must have been in robot mode when implementing the mailboxer gem and added the  `redirect_back_or(path)` method to the application controller. For some reason I thought I added it ages ago so it was irrelivent. Thanks so much for your help